# Free alternative for threadfix?

Tags: gratis, automation, security

Since threadfix (https://www.threadfix.it/) is not free anymore - is there a free alternative ? Threadfix is software that aggregates various security vulnerability reports and does trending.

The software should be able to

- take in vulnerability report
- de-duplicate issues and highlight trends
- plus is if it can take in industry-standard vulnerability report files (like output from OWASP ZAP), but in worst case I can write some transformations

Comment: Please explain what threadfix is and include a link.